# Access Rows by integers and Columns by labels Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

My data is like this:

*[First row is headers]*

```
Name,Email,Age
Sachith,ko@gmail.com,23
Sim,sm@gmail.com,234
Yoshi,yosi@hotmail.com,2345
sarla,sarla@gmail.com,234
```

I would like to access elements such that rows are specified as integers and columns by labels. i.e for *Sim* I would like to access it as *[1,'Name']* and so-on

My question is should I use **loc** or **ix**?

Looking at the documentation, I am confused as to what is a pandas index? Is it used to access rows or columns or both? When I try to print the indices of this data, I get a (4,) dtype=int64 array of [0,1,2,3]. So , are columns not part of the index?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), because `ix` is [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated).

```
print (df)
      Name             Email   Age
0  Sachith      ko@gmail.com    23
1      Sim      sm@gmail.com   234
2    Yoshi  yosi@hotmail.com  2345
3    sarla   sarla@gmail.com   234

#select by label 1 and label Name    
a = df.loc[1, 'Name']
print (a)
Sim
```

But if need select index by position (need `iloc`) and columns by labels (need `loc`) together:

```
df = df.set_index('Email')
print (df)
                     Name   Age
Email                          
ko@gmail.com      Sachith    23
sm@gmail.com          Sim   234
yosi@hotmail.com    Yoshi  2345
sarla@gmail.com     sarla   234
```

get label of second index by `df.index[1]`:

```
a = df.loc[df.index[1], 'Name']
print (a)
Sim
```

Or get position of label by [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
a = df.iloc[1, df.columns.get_loc('Name')]
print (a)
Sim
```

Comment: But , it is mentioned that loc only works with label based indexer. However, aren't the indices here integers? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I am still unclear on one thing. What is the difference between df.loc[1, 'Name'] and df.loc[df.index[1], 'Name']? I don't understand how df.loc[1, 'Name'] as the 1 is an integer and loc only takes label based indexing.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it, correct me if I am wrong. if the index is sequential and starts from 0, then label of a index is equal to its position. So, df.loc[1,'Name'] is actually looking for the index with label 1 and it happens to be at position 1